# Element type is invalid React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been having this error for hours and I don't know how to fix it, it's driving me crazy. In this shortcode here, I keep getting this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import {Application} from "./src/Application.js";

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isReady: false,
        };
    }
    componentWillMount = async() => {
        await Font.loadAsync({
            Roboto: require('./node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
            Roboto_medium: require('./node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf')
        });
        this.setState({isReady: true,});
    };

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isReady) {
            return <ActivityIndicator />
        }
        return (
            <Application/>
        );
    }
}


export default App;
```

The error pointed to `_callee$` in `18:16`, which is this line

```
this.setState({isReady: true,});
```

What could be causing this and a possible solution?

I tried importing `import {Application} from "./src/Application.js"` without `{}` before, but it also returned the error of

*Check the render method of `_default`*

Edited: Added "Application.js"

```
import React from 'react';
import Root from "native-base";
import { createAppContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import Home from "./screens/home/index";
import Email from "./screens/email/index";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen";
import SideBar from "./screens/SideBar/SideBar";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: Home},
        //Email: { screen: Email},
        ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreen}
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        contentOptions: {
            activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
        },
        contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props}/>
    }
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator (
    {
        Drawer: {screen: Drawer}
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Drawer",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default () =>
    <Root>
        <AppContainer/>
    </Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this statement,

```
export default () =>
    <Root>
        <AppContainer/>
    </Root>
```

Without parentheses,it will interpreted as

```
export default () =>();
    <Root>
        <AppContainer/>
    </Root>
```

So,it will return `undefined` which is not valid react element.Because of this above error will occur.

wrap the `export default` statement with `()`.It should be

```
  export default () =>( 
                       <Root> <AppContainer/></Root> 
                      );
```

OR

```
export default () =>( <Root> <AppContainer/></Root> );
```

And import should be

```
import Application from "./src/Application";
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried changing the import as you said, but it returned the following error   *Check the render method of _default* . If I dont change it and only change the `export default () => (<Root> <AppContainer/></Root>);` . The error remains

Answer (score 1):

Try

import * as Application from './src/application.js';

You are not exporting a named item but just a function byt you are trying to import a named item.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your way and got a new error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object`

Comment: tested it but I do not get you exception so I cannot give any more insights, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

You are probably importing your components the wrong way.

How are you exporting `Application` in `Application.js` ?

Maybe remove `{}` will fix it

```
import Application from "./src/Application.js";
```

There is two ways you can `export`/`import`

```
export function ...
// another file 
import {...} from '...'
```

Or using the `default` export

```
export default function ...
// another file
import ... from '...'
```

If you want to import it like

```
import {Application} from "./src/Application.js";
```

You should be exporting it like

```
export function Application...
```

And if you look ate what the error says...

> ...You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: I tried without {} initially. If I do that, this line would have this error  return (
            <Application/>
        );

Comment: @AnhMinhTran please show what is inisde  `./src/Application.js`

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are exporting Application correctly from Application.js.
It should just be "export Application".